# After Magento update(2.1.9>2.2.2) JS error on admin dashboard

Tags: magento2, admin, magento2.2, dashboard

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token } in JSON at position 33
```

Specifically, this line inside page's html is causing the error:

```
<script type="text/x-magento-init">{"*": {"Magento_Ui/js/core/app": }}</script>
```

`"Magento_Ui/js/core/app"` doesn't have a value.

I've already cleared all the exceptions on the front-end relating to xml configuration.

Can somebody point me the right direction? I'm still discovering new Magento2 AJAX request flow.

**Edit/solution:**

the problem was cause by a single module. Removing its settings from `core_config_data` and clearing the cache fixed the problem - the settings were regenerated.

Comment: Can you tell us which one made that error please?

Comment: @Aurélien I don't remember the name now because I have disabled several modules at that time and I don't want to guess. The problem was that I removed the module files but left database entry so Magento saw it as enabled.

Answer (score 2):

This bug related to error during json_encode in \Magento\Ui\TemplateEngine\Xhtml\Result::appendLayoutConfiguration method, in my case error was 'Malformed UTF-8 characters, possibly incorrectly encoded'. I used json_last_error_msg() to get it.

My solution is to create plugin for appendLayoutConfiguration() function:

```
public function aroundAppendLayoutConfiguration(
    \Magento\Ui\TemplateEngine\Xhtml\Result $result,
    \Closure $closure
) {
    $layoutConfiguration = $this->wrapContent(json_encode($this->utf8ize($this->structure->generate($this->component))));
    $this->template->append($layoutConfiguration);
}
```

Here is utf8ize() function:

```
/**
 * @param $data
 * @return array|string
 */
public function utf8ize($data) {
    if (is_array($data))
        foreach ($data as $key => $value)
            $data[$key] = $this->utf8ize($value);

    else if(is_object($data))
        foreach ($data as $key => $value)
            $data->$key = $this->utf8ize($value);

    else
        return utf8_encode($data);

    return $data;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, you saved my time :D